# Append trailing slash to cURL file upload

Tags: curl, django-rest-framework

I'm using cURL to test the REST API of a Django app (Apache server) that uses Django Rest Framework. The problem I'm encountering is that the upload URL requires a trailing slash, but using the following cURL approach does not append a trailing slash:

```
curl -i -b cookie.txt -X PUT -T "somefile.txt" http://myserver/api/upload/
```

From cURL man I know:

> If there is no file part in the specified URL, Curl will append the local file name. NOTE that you must use a trailing / on the last directory to really prove to Curl that there is no file name or curl will think that your last directory name is the remote file name to use.

However, cURL doesn't put a trailing slash after the filename it automatically appends. So, I can't find a way to get cURL to make the URL `http://myserver/api/upload/somefile.txt/` instead of `http://myserver/api/upload/somefile.txt`

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the cURL users mailing list (curl-users@cool.haxx.se):

> When doing a HTTP PUT, you're supposed to identify the resource you're about to create with the request. I would claim an API that requires it to have a trailing slash is a bit on the broken side.
>
> But no, curl cannot send a PUT to such a URL in any easy way I can think of. libcurl itself can of course though, so a simple fix is probably to write a simple program in a language with a libcurl binding.